# JProfiler: Length of sql command

Tags: jprofiler

profiler Database / JDBC / Events show in description sql statement.
ok.

Full statement can be shown in "Show row details".
ok.

But - some statements are too long (over 10.000 chars) and are trimmed in this detail.

How to enlarge space for long statementes?

Comment: Please consider revisiting your question and provide some clear insights. what are you trying, what is the issue and what is the expected output. This otherwise is har to get what you are trying to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Currently the limit of 10000 characters is not configurable. In JProfiler 8.1.2 you will be able to pass the VM parameter

```
-Djprofiler.maximumDescriptionSize=[maximum size < 65536]
```

to the profiled VM (not the JProfiler GUI) to increase this limit.

---

**Update 2016-02-04:**

From JProfiler 9.2 onward, there will be a corresponding setting on the "JEE & probes" tab of the profiling settings dialog.